# SVN branching - how can I only keep branched files?

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging, visual-sourcesafe

In our enterprise project we used to use VSS. Our project for 6 customers were single source, so we only needed to keep a "fullVersion" and "branched" directories for our version managements. In order to get the sources of customer1, we first get the fullversion and then branched for customer1(it was been replaced to general sources).

We have migrated to SVN. But the question now is that if I want to have the same functionality, I need to keep the whole project in "fullVersion" and in every "branches". becuase switching in SVN does the same functionality. Am I right?
Please help me to find the solution to this problem, so I can keep one general source, and only branched files of different customer?

Answer (score 1):

In common case - yes, branch in Subversion contain full tree of project with unmodified, contrary to trunk, and branch-related changes. In you case in means: every change in core must be replicated (by merge) in customer-branches

Depending from structure of project (and version of SVN - you have fresh SVN, isn't it?) you can think about using SVN externals in order to link (stored somewhere) different branched-files from common single core-codebase

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean I should add externals,(in my branched project to my base project) in order to keep them sync?

Comment: @animgr - it depends... external resources can be branched files or just core